# "The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved" using EMF

Tags: maven, eclipse-emf, ecore

I just cloned a Maven project from GitHub with Ecore models. I'm using the EMF version.

This project has a lot of java classes. The error I get is "The import org.eclipse.cannot be resolved".

I already checked the Java Build Path and it's pointing to the JDK version (17) installed in my system.

I've been working in other similar proyects without any problem. I also tried many EMF versions and it doesn't matter.

Dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans/yamlbeans -->
        <!-- 1.14 version is not available in Maven Central Repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>yamlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

So I'm a bit stuck... Any ideas?

I tried to clean the proyect, restart EMF but nothing worked.

Comment: Why don't you better put the complete output and the command that is producing the error?

Comment: There is no command producing the error. It's a pre compile error. 

The lines producing the errors are like this: import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EcorePackage;

Comment: so the project compiles itself? by magic? Try to build it from command line, so we can have a stack trace or something to hepl you.